# speed up mplotlib when plotting live serial data

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino

I am using an Arduino to create a 3d lidar scan of the area around it, and sending x,y,z coordinates over serial to a python script to visualize the data live.  The issue I've run into is that mplotlib is much too slow to keep up with the stream.  I have a feeling this is due to completely redrawing the plot, but I have not found a solution.  I write s1000 over serial to start the lidar scan, and sending a x,y,z coordinate once per second.

```
import serial
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplotlib library
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from drawnow import *
from matplotlib import animation
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM7',9600,timeout=5)
ser.flushInput()
time.sleep(5)
ser.write(bytes(b's1000'))

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.set_xlim3d(-255, 255)
ax.set_ylim3d(-255, 255)
ax.set_zlim3d(-255, 255)

x=list()
y=list()
z=list()


while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        data = str(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        xyz = data.split(", ")
        dx = float(xyz[0])
        dy = float(xyz[1])
        dz = float(xyz[2].replace(";",""))
        x.append(dx);
        y.append(dy);
        z.append(dz);

        ax.scatter(x,y,z, c='r',marker='o')
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.0001)

    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        ser.close()
        break
```

Comment: you're creating new artists (scatter elements) with each loop. look at the animations demos on the matplotlib webpage to see how to modify existing artists with new data